# define get or set in c#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, get

friends i have problem with using get or set in class in c#
 when i use get or set in gives error(invalid token { in class)
pls, see below code,i have this problem in it

```
static int abcd
{  
    get           
    {  
       return  _abcd; 
    }  
}
```

thanx

this is the complete code,i dont have this problem with any of your codes but just this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
   class Program
   {
      class Car
      {
         private int _speed;  
         public int Speed;
         {
              get
              {
                return _speed
              }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra `}` somewhere in your class.

Comment: The code you've written here is just fine, the problem may lay somewhere else in your code. Make sure each block of code you have is properly closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The snippet you have posted is fine as it is, also in regards to the error, as it has the correct number of `{` to `}` and in the right order.

Look at where you have placed it (possibly outside of a class), or look for extra `}` in the file.

**Update:** (following edit in question)

Your issue is here:

```
public int Speed; // <-- ; should not be here
```

And:

```
return _speed // <-- missing the ;
```

The property should be implemented like this:

```
public int Speed
{
   get
   {
      return _speed;
   }
}
```

Comment: this is the complete code,i dont have this problem with any of your codes but just this:
    class Car{
        private int _speed;  
        public int Speed;
    {
       get
       {
        return _speed
        }
}

Comment: @arash - answer updated. You did not implement the property correctly.

Answer (score 7):

There are **two** errors in your code.

- You have a semicolon where there shouldn't be one (spotted by Oded).
- You are missing a semicolon where there should be one.

Try this instead:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        class Car
        {
            private int _speed;  
            public int Speed     // <-- no semicolon here.
            {
                get
                {
                    return _speed;  // <-- here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that the code you originally posted was formatted badly. I would suggest that you format your document automatically in Visual Studio to make the braces line up. This should make the error more obvious. When the formatting of the code looks wrong you know that there is an error nearby. You can find this option in the menu: Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document or use the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl-E D for me, but might be different for you, depending on your settings).

I would also suggest that you consider using [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) instead of writing the getter out in full:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        class Car
        {
            public int Speed { get; private set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to drop the semicolon after `public int Speed` in your first example.

Comment: @Dirk D: Thanks. So actually there were two errors in his code! It just shows that the auto-implemented property is much easier to get right and definitely the way to go for simple properties.

Comment: Actually it was @Oded who spotted it first in his answer :)

Comment: @Dirk D: Oh, right I didn't see that. But to be fair, you were the one that noticed the error in my code... so huge credits for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
class Foo
{
    static int _abcd;

    static int Abcd
    {
       get { return _abcd; }
       set { _abcd = value; }    
    }
}
```