# define get or set in c# 2

Tags: c#

friends i have problem with using get or set in class in c#
 when i use get or set in gives error(invalid token { in class)
pls, see below code,i have this problem in it

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
      class Car
      {
        private int _speed;  
        public int Speed;
        {
          get
          {
           return _speed
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do _not_ post the same question again. Just go through the original and update it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483773/define-get-or-set-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi colon after Speed. It should be:

```
public int Speed
{ 
     get { return _speed; } 
}
```

Comment: it gives error:
Error 2 Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: @arash - the property is implemented correctly in the answer here. It belongs in a _class_. Compare it to _your_ `Speed` property.